# Replace column comma separator in csv file and handle fields with single quotes around value

Tags: c#, powershell

A system is producing a csv file which i have no influence over.

There are two columns where the values MAYBE enclosed in a pair of single quotes if the data itself contains commas.

Example Data - 4 columns

```
123,'abc,def,ghf',ajajaj,1 
345,abdf,'abc,def,ghi',2
556,abdf,def,3
999,'a,b,d','d,e,f',4
```

Result I want using powershell...

The commas that are not part of the data - meaning those commas that separate the fields are replaced with a specified delimiter (in the case below pipe-star). Those commas that are in between a pair of single quotes remain as commas.

Result

```
123|*'abc,def,ghf'|*ajajaj|*1 
345|*abdf|*'abc,def,ghi'|*2
556|*abdf|*def|*3
999|*'a,b,d'|*'d,e,f'|*4
```

I would like to do this is power-shell or c# net if  possible using a reg expression however I don't know how to do this.

Comment: In .net I'd use some simple CSV reader/writer library to line by line just read in with comma and write out with pipe as separator, but actually I just noticed the dev of one of the oldest and most well used CSV libs I use, Jouni Heikniemi, has some words on powershell's Import-Csv cmdlet - http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2010/01/powershell-basics-1-reading-and-parsing-csv/ - paired with the relevant Export-Csv https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7 - it might be as simple to Import/Export in powershell

Comment: Do you really need a 2-character delimiter, `|*`, or did you just use that for illustrative purposes?

Comment: |* is just for illustrative purposes. The field separator could just be a single pipe.

Comment: I just found a near answer however it only surrounds the field values enclosed in single quotes with the new-delimiter it doesn't replace the field-separator for those field values not enclosed with single quotes...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127547/handle-a-csv-file-with-single-quoted-string-and-occasional-comma-or-single-quote/60006192?noredirect=1#comment106123524_60006192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think this would create a strangely formatted CSV file, with PowerShell you can use the `switch` together with the `-Regex` and `-File` parameters. This is probably the fastest way to handle large files and it takes just a few lines of code:

```
# create a regex that will find comma's unless they are inside single quotes
$commaUnlessQuoted = ",(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)"

$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\test.csv' {
    # added -replace "'" to also remove the single quotes as commented
    default { $_ -replace "$commaUnlessQuoted", '|*' -replace "'" }
}

# output to console
$result

# output to new (sort-of) CSV file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\testoutput.csv'
```

---

**Update**

As [mklement0 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008760/9898643) the code above does the job, but at the expence of creating the updated data as array in memory **completely** before writing to the output file.
If this is a problem (file too large to fit the available memory), you can also change the code to read/replace a line from the original and write out that line immediately to the output file.

This next approach will hardly use up any memory, but of course at the expence of doing a lot more write actions on disk..

```
# make sure this is an absolute path for .NET
$outputFile = 'D:\output.csv'
$inputFile  = 'D:\input.csv'

# create a regex that will find comma's unless they are inside single quotes
$commaUnlessQuoted = ",(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)"

# create a StreamWriter object. Uses UTF8Encoding without BOM (Byte Order Mark) by default.
# if you need a different encoding for the output file, use for instance
# $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputFile, $false, [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputFile)
switch -Regex -File $inputFile {
    default {
        # added -replace "'" to also remove the single quotes as commented
        $line = $_ -replace "$commaUnlessQuoted", '|*' -replace "'"
        $writer.WriteLine($line)
        # if you want, uncomment the next line to show on console
        # $line
    }
}

# remove the StreamWriter object from memory when done
$writer.Dispose()
```

Result:

> ```
> 123|*abc,def,ghf|*ajajaj|*1 
> 345|*abdf|*abc,def,ghi|*2
> 556|*abdf|*def|*3
> 999|*a,b,d|*d,e,f|*4
> ```

Regex details:

```
,                 Match the character “,” literally
(?=               Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   (              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
      [^']        Match any character that is NOT a “'”
         *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      '           Match the character “'” literally
      [^']        Match any character that is NOT a “'”
         *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      '           Match the character “'” literally
   )*             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   [^']           Match any character that is NOT a “'”
      *           Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   $              Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)
```

Comment: This works - thanks very much! I have just tested on a small file and it worked. I am currently running against the largest file I have. I have to write out the results to the original file - which I did using your code. One mistake on my part I do need to remove the single quotes as well before writing back to the original file - any suggestions?

Comment: @IanCarrick Sure just add another replace: `-replace "'"` to the line so it becomes `default { $_ -replace "$commaUnlessQuoted", '|*' -replace "'" }`

Comment: @IanCarrick I have added new updated code as alternative for doing the job without having such a large impact on the available memory in your system.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update I am running the complete script against my largest file...

Comment: I have accepted your answer as the one to answer the question and you went above and beyond - thank you from a total new PowerShell developer.

Answer (score 1):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60007457/45375) is concise and efficient.

Let me complement with the following solution, which:

- shows **how to parse each CSV row into an array of field values**, based on recognizing the embedded `'...'` quoting (it could easily be adapted to `"..."` quoting), *without* including the `'` chars. in the output (which aren't syntactically needed anymore, if a delimiter such as `|` is used instead.
- shows **a faster way to write the output file**, using [`System.IO.File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.WriteAllLines)

```bsh
# In and output file paths.
# IMPORTANT: To use file paths with .NET methods, as below, always use
#            FULL PATHS, because .NET's current directory differs from PowerShell's
$inPath = "$PWD/input.csv"
$outPath = "$PWD/output.csv"

[IO.File]::WriteAllLines(
  $outPath,
  # CAVEAT: Even though ReadLines() enumerates *lazily* itself,
  #         applying PowerShell's .ForEach() method to it causes the lines
  #         to all be collected in memory  first.
  [IO.File]::ReadLines($inPath).ForEach({
    # Parse the row into field values, whether they're single-quoted or not.
    $fieldValues = $_ -split "(?x) ,? ( '[^']*' | [^,]* ) ,?" -ne '' -replace "'"
    # Join the field values - without single quotes - to form a row with the
    # new delimiter.
    $fieldValues -join '|'
  })
)
```

<sup>* For brevity I've omitted an important optimization: `if (-not $_.Contains("'")) { $_.Replace(",", "|") }` could be used to process lines that contain no `'` chars. much more quickly.

* `-split`, the regex-based [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) is used to split the lines into fields.

* Inline option `(?x)` is used to make the regex more readable, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53328805/45375).</sup>

As the code comments state, the solution above still **loads the entire file into memory**.

**Use of the *pipeline* is required to avoid that**, which **slows the solution down considerably**, however:

```
& {
 foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($inPath)) {
    $fieldValues = $line -split "(?x) ,? ( '[^']*' | [^,]* ) ,?" -ne '' -replace "'"
    $fieldValues -join '|'
  }
} | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 $outPath
```

With either solution, the output file ends up containing the following (note the absence of the `'` chars.):

```
123|abc,def,ghf|ajajaj|1
345|abdf|abc,def,ghi|2
556|abdf|def|3
999|a,b,d|d,e,f|4
```