# Convert date format to CSV export

Tags: sql, powershell, csv

I'm new to Poweshell, and I made a script that the result of an SQL Select is exported to csv. However I have two columns that are in the date format mm-dd-yyyy and I would like it to be in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm: ss.fff. I was able to transform just one column, in the other I couldn't find a way to convert.

Could someone help me to convert the two columns?

```
#Connect to SQL and run QUERY 
$SQLServer = "xxxx" 
$SQLDBName = "xxxx"
$SQLUsername = "xxxx"
$SQLPassword = "nxxx"

$OuputFile = "c:\SQL_Export.csv"

$SqlQuery = "SELECT  
    rtrim(HANDLE) as Handle,
    rtrim(EMPRESA) as Empresa,
    rtrim(FILIAL) as Filial,
    rtrim(OPERACAO) as Operacao,
    rtrim(PESSOA) as Pessoa,
    rtrim(dataemissao) as Dataemissao,
    rtrim(documentodigitado) as Documentodigitado,
    rtrim(dataultimaliq) as Dataultimaliq,
    rtrim(ehprevisao) as Ehprevisao,
    rtrim(status) as Status,
    rtrim(entradasaida) as Entradasaida
  FROM [$SQLDBName].[dbo].[FN_DOCUMENTOS]
  where DATAULTIMALIQ >= '20200101'
  ORDER BY handle ASC"

##Delete the output file if it already exists
If (Test-Path $OuputFile ){
    Remove-Item $OuputFile
}

Write-Host "INFO: Exporting data from $SQLDBName to $OuputFile" -foregroundcolor white -backgroundcolor blue

## - Connect to SQL Server using non-SMO class 'System.Data':
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $SQLUsername; Password = $SQLPassword"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
$SqlConnection.Close() 

#Output RESULTS to CSV
$DataSet.Tables[0] | select-Object -ExcludeProperty Dataemissao @{Name="Dataemissao";Expression={([datetime]$_.Dataemissao).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}}, * | Export-Csv $OuputFile
(Get-Content $OuputFile) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Set-Content $OuputFile -Encoding `UTF8`
```

the columns I need to convert are, "Dataemissao" and "Dataultimaliq"

Comment: Please tell us what _the other_ date field is and what its current format to convert looks like. Since the field names are all Portuguese (?) I cannot read..

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, the fields are in portuguese. I need to convert the following fields:
"Dataemissao" and "Dataultimaliq"

Comment: the date format in the CSV file is as follows: Feb 12 2020 12:00 AM, however I would like to come 02.12.2020 12: 00: 00.000

Comment: on this line
`select-Object -ExcludeProperty Dataemissao @ {Name = "Dataemissao"; Expression = {([datetime] $ _. Dataemissao) .ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm: ss.fff")}}
`
I convert the field "Dataemissao" however, I tried some ways to do the same with the field "Dataultimaliq", but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you would need a very long line in the Select-Object:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | 
    Select-Object -ExcludeProperty Dataemissao, Dataultimaliq @{Name = "Dataemissao";   Expression= { '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}'-f [datetime]$_.Dataemissao }},
                  @{Name = "Dataultimaliq"; Expression= { '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}'-f [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Dataultimaliq, 'MMM dd yyyy hh:mm tt', [cultureinfo]"en-US") }},
                  * | Export-Csv -Path $OuputFile -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

OR, you could add a small helper function above the code like

```
function Format-Date () {
    param (
        [string]$dateString,
        [string]$format = 'MMM dd yyyy hh:mm tt'
    )
    $date = Get-Date
    if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($dateString, $format, [cultureinfo]"en-US", 0, [ref]$date)) {
        return '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}'-f $date
    }
}
```

and use that for the `Dataultimaliq`:

```
@{Name = "Dataultimaliq"; Expression= { Format-Date $_.Dataultimaliq }},
```

As you can see, I've put a second parameter `$format` in that defaults to ''MMM dd yyyy hh:mm tt', because that is the format the returned Dataultimaliq field is in.
You can also use that on the Dataemissao field, but I don't know what format that is in.. (apparently, your system can cast it to a DateTime object without any problems)

<sup>I see you read the csv file in later and remove the quotes from it. This can lead to various problems, because sometimes quotes are needed in a CSV file and you should not simply remove all of them. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60007457/9898643) for code how you can do that safely</sup>

P.S. `'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}'-f [datetime]$_.Dataemissao` is a more 'PowerShelly' way of getting a date in a specific format. It returns the same as `([datetime]$_.Dataemissao).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")`, but is more concise.